# Crontab - Linux - EC2 - Python - No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, cron, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run a Python script (it's a webscraping) via crontab on EC2. But it's not working.

Here is my task:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local / bin: / sbin: / bin: / usr / sbin: / usr / bin
* * / 2 * * * / usr / bin / python /home/ec2-user/LATAM_v1.py
```

I got emails from the system that says that pandas is not installed.

But it is installed.

I've also run the script directly in the shell:

```
/home/ec2-user/LATAM_v1.py
/ usr / bin / python home / ec2-user / LATAM_v1.py
```

Both ways worked.

I already checked the status of the cron and the daemon if they are running, which they are.

Here is the error:

```
From root@ip-172-31-3-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal  Sun Apr 12 10:10:02 2020
Return-Path: <root@ip-172-31-3-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal>
Received: from ip-172-31-3-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by ip-172-31-3-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id 03CDA2Lb008039
        for <root@ip-172-31-3-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal>; Sun, 12 Apr 2020 10:10:02 -0300
Received: (from root@localhost)
        by ip-172-31-3-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id 03CDA2W8008038;
        Sun, 12 Apr 2020 10:10:02 -0300
Date: Sun, 12 Apr 2020 10:10:02 -0300
Message-Id: <202004121310.03CDA2W8008038@ip-172-31-3-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal>
From: root@ip-172-31-3-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal (Cron Daemon)
To: root@ip-172-31-3-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal
Subject: Cron <root@ip-172-31-3-2> /usr/bin/python /home/ec2-user/LATAM_v1.py
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/bash>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=root>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/LATAM_v1.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

This is the version of the machine:
NAME = "Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION = "2018.03"
ID = "amzn"
ID_LIKE = "rhel fedora"
PRETTY_NAME = "Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
```

I already reviewed Stackoverflow, I got many answers and etc., but nothing worked here.

I am not familiar with Linux. If anyone knows how to solve it and explain it step by step, I would be thankfully.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely a python path issue.  Python packages can be installed in several locations:

```
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
~/project_path/venv/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
```

You have likely installed pandas in the first location, and when cron runs it does not have that location in the python path.  You can fix this by setting the python path in your cron script (use your correct python version):

```
 PYTHONPATH=/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Or you can install pandas globally:

```
 sudo -H pip install pandas
```

Or you can learn to use [virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) in which case you would activate your environment first, either directly in the cron separated by && or create a shell script to activate and run your python from and call that from cron.  If you have multiple projects that rely on different versions of python or libraries, this is the preferred method of handling that.